# Check only one checkbox and uncheck previous checked checkbox

Tags: ionic-framework

[image: This is my interface i can't select only one checkbox at a time]

I wanted that when I change my selection in my checkbox the only selected checkbox will be selected and the previous selected checkbox will be uncheck.
My code is working but i really wanted to select only one checkbox.
In my view.

```
      <center><table></center>
      <tr> 
      <th><center>
      List of Names</center></th>
      <th colspan="3">
      Actions
      </th></tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="role in roles">
      <td>
      <label>
      <ion-checkbox ng-model="isChecked" ng-   
      change="format(isChecked,role,$index)" 
      ng-init="isChecked=false"><div class="wew">
      {{role}}
      </div></ion-checkbox>
      </label> 
      </td>
      <td>
     <button ng-hide="!isChecked" ng-click="present()">P </button> </td>
     <td>
      <button ng-hide="!isChecked"  ng-click="late()">L</button></td>
      <td><button ng-hide="!isChecked" ng-click="absentss()">A</button></td>
      <td><button ng-hide="!isChecked" ng-click="delete()">D</button></td>
       </tr> </table>
```

And I think in my controller is the part where i need to change my codes to achieved the correct result.

```
        $scope.isChecked = false;
        $scope.selected = [];
        $scope.format = function (isChecked, role, index) {
        if (isChecked==true) {
        $scope.selected.push(role);
        }
        else {
        var _index = $scope.selected.indexOf(role);
        $scope.selected.splice(_index, 1);
        }
        var students = $scope.selected;
        console.log(students);
        for( var s=0; s<students.length; s++) {
         $scope.stud = [
        students[s]
        ]
        };
```

Thank you in advanced! I hope that someone can help in this matter.

Comment: I think radio buttons are used for that.

Comment: but i saw some example for checkbox and it works that only one checkbox can be selected.

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes are for multiple selections within a group.
Use radio buttons instead.

Answer (score 0):

```html
Example With AngularJs
This is way you can also implement.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('app', []).controller('appc', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.selected = 'other';  //default selection
      }
    ]);
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="appc">
  <label>SELECTED: {{selected}}</label>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='male'" ng-true-value="'male'" ng-model="selected">Male
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='female'" ng-true-value="'female'" ng-model="selected">Female
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="selected=='other'" ng-true-value="'other'" ng-model="selected">Other
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: $http.post(link1, {section: section}).success(function(attendance){
             for(a = 0; a<attendance.length; a++){
              $scope.roles = [
              attendance[0].Full_Name,
              attendance[1].Full_Name,
              attendance[2].Full_Name,
              attendance[3].Full_Name,
              attendance[4].Full_Name,
              attendance[5].Full_Name,
              attendance[6].Full_Name,
              attendance[7].Full_Name,
              attendance[8].Full_Name,
              attendance[9].Full_Name,
              ]
}          
  })

Comment: that is the code where im getting my values in ng-repeat="role in roles"

Comment: can you provide me na a related example with that kind of ng-repeat